# Using context API (React.js) to change only a particular key in state object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context, use-context

I am using context API in react for managing state. For this I have created a file **AppContext.js** where I have created context and Provider:

```
import { useState, createContext } from "react";

export const AppContext = createContext();

export const AppProvider = (props) => {
   const [appdata, setAppdata] = useState({
      data1: "this is data1",
      data2: "this is data2",
   });

   return (
      <AppContext.Provider value={[appdata, setAppdata]}>
         {props.children}
      </AppContext.Provider>
   );
};
```

I have imported this Provider in the parent component of the app i.e **App.js**. Also I have wrapped the `<AppChild/>` component in the Provider.

```
import AppChild from "./AppChild";
import { AppProvider } from "./AppContext";

const App = () => {
   return (
      <AppProvider>
         <div className="App">hello</div>
         <AppChild />
      </AppProvider>
   );
};

export default App;
```

Now from `AppChild` component, I only needed to update the `data1` key of my state. For this I have created a button with a `onClick` through which I will be changing my state. I have used to following code in **AppChild.js** for this:

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { AppContext } from "./AppContext";

const AppChild = () => {
   const [appdata, setAppdata] = useContext(AppContext);
   return (
      <div>
         <h3 style={{ color: "red" }}>Data for Appchild: {appdata.data1}</h3>
         <button
            onClick={() =>
               setAppdata((prev) => {
                  prev.data1 = "updated data1";
                  return prev;
               })
            }
         >
            click to change
         </button>
      </div>
   );
};

export default AppChild;
```

But when I click the button, the text inside the `<h3>` block is not changing. Although when I change the whole state by passing the whole object directly to `setAppdata` as shown below,
[image: new code]

This way the state updates successfully. Why is the first method not working where I only wanted to change the `data1` key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating state in wrong way so it is not working. This is how you should update state

```
<button
 onClick={() =>
   setAppdata((prevState) => ({
     ...prevState,
     data1: "Your New Data"
        }))
      }
    >
        click to change
      </button>
```

Comment: Your solution works. But can you tell what is wrong in my method which stops it from working? As far as I know setAppdata() takes an implicit function. you have directly used ()=>("hello") while I have used ()=>{return "hello"}. Both are technically same if I am not wrong. Please explain...

Comment: You are also updating state but you are modifying `state` directly which won't cause re-render.  [read this](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly) for more info

Comment: Oh, got it! Thanks a lot!